# expressing inclusive OR using exclusive OR.

Tags: logic

On page 5 of Hamilton`s mathematical logic book, it's been stated that we can express A or B or both using XOR, as also possible to express negation and conjunction using XOR.

I couldn't find any suitable form. What is the form to express $A \vee B$ using XOR?

Comment: If you have negation and conjunction, you don't need XOR at all!  Negation and conjunction are a complete set of connectives - they can be used to express every connective.

Comment: @CarlMummert I know, but assuming we have defined disjunction as the exclusive OR, how can we express the inclusive OR using the new defined disjunction?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The question states you have conjunction and negation. Just use those and ignore the XOR entirely.

Comment: @CarlMummert you can take a look at page 5 of Hamilton's logic book where XOR is expressed using OR, while expressing OR using XOR has been left as an exercise.

Comment: @CarlMummert Check out the answer below, it clarifies the point I was trying to reach

Comment: I think you perhaps meant to ask (as the title suggests) how to express ordinary "or" (logical disjunction) using XOR (exclusive-or), hence the phrase "express A or B or both".  It is also possible to express negation with XOR, and to express "and" (logical conjunction) with XOR.  Should your Question be edited to state this more clearly?  I'll assume so.  You can rollback my edit if this is not the case.

Comment: I just quoted from Hamilton`s logic book! and I don't see any ambiguity in the question I've asked, as the answers below verify my statement. @hardmath

Comment: Of course you don't see the ambiguity, as you "just quoted" from the book and the context is clear in your mind.  If you meant express $A \vee B$ using XOR, then separately express the same using negation and conjunction, you could have stated this multiple part question better.  I'll rollback my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of looking at this is that with AND and XOR you are essentially doing arithmetic modulo 2. Indeed, if $\varphi:Var\to\{0,1\}$ is a valuation of the variables in $Var$ (identifying $1$ with True and $0$ with False), for any expressions $A,B$

- $\varphi(A\ AND\ B) = \varphi(A)\cdot\varphi(B)$,
- $\varphi(A\ XOR\ B) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(B) \mod 2$, and
- $\varphi(NOT\ A) = 1 - \varphi(A) \mod 2$ ( $= 1 + \varphi(A) \mod 2$).

Then using these, you can obtain arbitrarily polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/2$, and these can express all Boolean functions. In particular for $OR$, we want $\varphi(A\ OR\ B) = 0$ if $\varphi(A)=\varphi(B)=0$, and $1$ otherwise; this can be achieved as

- $\varphi(A\ OR\ B) = \varphi(A) + \varphi(B) + \varphi(A)\varphi(B) \mod 2 = \varphi((A\ XOR\ B)\ XOR\ (A\ AND\ B))$ (Omnomnomnom's first solution), or
- $\varphi(A\ OR\ B) = 1 - (1 - \varphi(A))(1 - \varphi(B)) \mod 2 = \varphi(NOT\  ((NOT\ A)\ AND\ (NOT\ B)))$ (Omnomnomnom's second solution).

Comment: Your answer is really a complete and detailed one. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it:
$$
A \, \mathsf{OR} \, B =
(A \; \mathsf{XOR} \; B)\,\mathsf{XOR}\, (A \;\mathsf{AND}\; B)
$$
Or, using just negation and conjunction, we of course have
$$
A \, \mathsf{OR} \, B = 
\mathsf{NOT}(\mathsf{NOT}(A) \; \mathsf{AND}\; \mathsf{NOT}(B))
$$
Interestingly, we can express XOR using "not" and "and" in a fairly obvious way, but we can also express "not" using "xor" with
$$
\mathsf{NOT}(A) = A \;\mathsf{XOR} \; [\mathsf{true}]
$$

Comment: Thank you, I checked the truth table and it was correct.